How put an id(like index value) on a tr
I need to put an id that represent that number of row in my tr
I put this code
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: _columns;let i = dataIndex;" [id]="i"></tr>

The problem is that the id is undefined

Anyone can help me to put the correct value?

You can set it like let dataIndex = index; and it should work as expected.
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  ...

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;let dataIndex = index"
    [id]="dataIndex"
  ></tr>
</table>

Full Code:
HTML:
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;let dataIndex = index"
    [id]="dataIndex"
  ></tr>
</table>

TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrl: 'table-basic-example.css',
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  imports: [MatTableModule],
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}

Stackblitz Demo
